# Holistic narrative on GHC

Tags: haskell, ghc

Haskell keeps surprising me, delightfully. For example, I came across a piece of code on *recursive fib array* instead of canonical *recursive fib function*, without sacrificing elegance, conciseness and simplicity.

```
ghci> fib = 0 .. 1 .. zipWith (+) fib (tail fib)
```

Although I believed *recursive fib array* should outperform greatly, I ran it on a retrocomputer deliberately, observing how it really worked out,

```
ghci> :set +s
ghci> fib !! 1000000
(107.07 secs, 44,216,491,400 bytes)
```

One CPU core ran at full speed while the memory consumption unnoticed any change. Obviously, the GC did its decent job on the realized fib array.

Not only the design of the language but also its implementation never fall short of pearls of wisdom. I'm wondering if there's a *holistic* narrative up to date on GHC implementation in addition to the definitive [user guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/).

**@EDIT**

To comply with the guideline posting and re-opening the question, I try to clarify and add up the following;

- It's not merely asking for some links for the reference, I doubt there's one approachable by Google-fu. I'm certainly glad to hear too, otherwise.
- I'd attribute this question to the heuristic type if it needs for classification.
- Very grateful that the valuable insightful comments and answers have gathered around the question. OTH, they enlighten me more specific on the question below;

Was GHC preemptive optimization involved to realize the said *recursive fib array*? How did GHC determine whether it should and could be optimized or not?

Preferably, could you provide high level overviews on GHC implementation and focus on *holistic* narrative on evaluation strategies and optimization techniques?

What kind of sound indicators are catering for positive GHC optimizations, when we write a piece of code in Haskell, ideally idiomatic?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Don't use ghci to benchmark code. Compiled code using optimization is the only valuable comparison.

Comment: You should provide a type annotation: `ghci> fib :: [Integer] ; fib = 0:1: ....`. Without that, `fib` gets a polymorphic type in GHCi, and that is likely to slow it down. Also, that will make it possible to cache values, which is not possible with polymorphic values. That should consume more memory for the cache.

Comment: The system hung with the type annotation

Comment: @ThomasM Well, the right way to prepare code for benchmarking is as close as possible to the way you intend to prepare your real code. If for some reason you care about the performance of your code in GHCi, then benchmarking it compiled and optimised would be misleading. Definitely the more normal situation is caring about the performance of compiled and optimised code, though, since if you're benchmarking at all you presumably care about performance enough not to leave the easy optimisations GHC already has on the table.

Comment: your new questions are too broad, need more focus, and / or are vague and unclear.

Comment: Given the nature of the question, I understand your concern despite it seeming opinionated.

Answer (score 4):

The #1 performance cost in your code is not understanding Haskell's evaluation model. GHC tries really hard to protect the programmer from mistakes of this form when compiling with optimizations, but ghci doesn't apply optimizations.

The problem here comes from `zipWith` being inappropriate for generating lists in which later elements have computational dependencies on earlier elements. When used that way, it commits the #1 Haskell performance error of producing a recursive data type that can be traversed in a way that allows the build-up of nested unevaluated expressions. And of course `(!!)` happens to traverse lists in exactly that way - it evaluates only the `(:)` constructors while counting down. Using `(!!)` is often a mistake for a number of reasons, but in this case I can't blame it. Proper evaluation discipline requires producers to ensure there's no bad consumption patterns, and `zipWith` cannot ensure that.

```
ghci> :set +s
ghci> let zipWith' f (x:xs) (y:ys) = let z = f x y in z `seq` z:zipWith' f xs ys; zipWith' _ _ _ = []
(0.01 secs, 33,216 bytes)
ghci> fib = 0:1:zipWith' (+) fib (tail fib)
(0.00 secs, 33,200 bytes)
ghci> fib !! 1000000
<extremely long result not included>
(6.91 secs, 43,747,100,560 bytes)
ghci> (fib !! 1000000) * 0
0
(3.77 secs, 43,545,996,856 bytes)
```

FWIW, that 6.91 seconds includes how long it took to print out the result, which was very slow on my terminal. You can see the execution time difference when all it has to print out is a single digit.  Still, 3.77 seconds is *slow* for this calculation. Actually compiling it would perform a lot better.

You can also see what the comments were remarking on demonstrated in that output. There's no sharing of computation between separate uses of `fib` because it's a typeclass-polymorphic value. That's relevant when using it multiple times, but it's not the performance issue you were encountering. The performance issue you encountered was neatly solved by (defining and) using `zipWith'`, which enables the caller to prevent a buildup of unevaluated expressions while traversing the `(:)` constructors in the resulting list.

Your definition of `fib` was essentially `fib = 0 : 1 : let x1 = 0 + 1 in x1 : let x2 = 1 + x1 in x2 : let x3 = x1 + x2 in x3 : let x4 = x2 + x3 in x4 : ...`. When traversing the result of that with `(!!)`, none of the intermediate `xN` values get evaluated until the entire thing gets added up. This introduces a lot of drag in the garbage collector, as you have a million nested applications of `(+)` that are never evaluated - they just sit in memory. My `zipWith'` function, on the other hand, causes each `xN` to be evaluated when the `(:)` constructor holding it is evaluated. This actually works nicely with the fact that `fib` isn't shared, because it allows ghci to discard old values of `xN`. The working set stays small, garbage collection is very quick, and the run time is mostly spent on necessary work.

If `zipWith'` is better, why did I have to define it myself? Well, because it's only better when you're tying knots like in the definition of `fib`. In more usual cases, `zipWith` doesn't generate any kind of nesting of unevaluated expressions, so the additional evaluation `zipWith'` provides might be counter-productive. Also, `zipWith'` doesn't magically make things better in more complicated cases involving knot tying. You still need to ensure the function passed to it does the proper amount of evaluation.

In general, understanding evaluation dependency in Haskell is a new skill that needs to be learned from the ground up. There are patterns where making everything locally good makes everything globally good. This might catch a lot of people by surprise, but the rule I described above is a good start: make sure there's no traversal patterns for recursive data that allow building up nested unevaluated expressions. If the producers do that, all consumers need to be only locally correct for everything to be globally correct. But you still need to learn how to do this. You need to learn to think about evaluation dependencies, what `seq` actually does, and what library functions do and don't do. There's a lot there, and it's very unfamiliar when coming from basically any other programming language.

To add to the difficulty, GHC's optimizations often paper over mistakes along these lines. It's easy to write code that would perform badly if evaluated as written, but GHC recognizes the problem and rewrites it to perform well. This can result in it being hard to predict when GHC will fix your code and when it won't. Some people don't learn that they're writing code using bad patterns until things get too complicated for GHC to see the problem - and at that point they've got something that's both mechanically complex and they never learned how to think about. It's best to learn these things early. And especially don't treat `-XStrict`, `-XStrictData`, or `-XUnliftedDataTypes` as magical solutions. These extensions exist because they solve certain problems, but they all still have usage patterns that go off the rails if you don't understand how things work.

Comment: thanks. I retested it with your `zipWith'`, and the total time was cut to one order of magnitude lower than before, but the GC throughput seemingly unchanged, still around 44 GB totally. I'm still wondering and learning what hot spots `zipWith'` has addressed to vastly boost the performance in terms of the execution time.

Comment: @sof Well yes, it's going to be about the same amount of memory allocated - it's still allocating a million `Integer` values, which are growing in required memory linearly. The question is how much is required to be resident simultaneously.

Comment: I'm very tempted to use unlifted data for `Data.HashMap` once I can get `SmallArray`s of unlifted data. I recognize that will absolutely trash performance of `fmap`, certain applications of `traverse`, and maybe a few other things, but the current arrangement requires an enormous amount of care not to forget to force anything in hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: GHC can also sometimes break performance, especially with the full laziness transformation.

Comment: plain `zipWith` is only a problem _if_ accessed with `!!`. accessed with ``(~~) (a:_) 0 = a ; (~~) (a:b) i = a `seq` ( b ~~ (i-1) )`` it's just (or almost) as fast: `let fib = 0:1:zipWith (+) fib (tail fib) in (take 10 . show $ fib ~~ 100000)`. it's better to have two accessors for _n_ functions than to have _2n_ functions (i.e. the forcing access is a common pattern). also, there's no nested expressions being created here, just a long linear chain of shallow expressions each dependent on its preceding one. it's not like nested `let`s that you show, but like one long `let`.

Comment: `zipWith'` though _is_ needed if we wanted to access it with e.g. `take 2 . drop 100000`, or we'd have to define the forcing `drop`... :) _or_, perhaps we could always use ``foldr (\x r->x`seq`(x:r)) []`` as an adaptor in the middle. (indeed it works, ``let fib = 0:1:zipWith (+) fib (tail fib) in (take 10 . show $ foldr (\x r->x`seq`(x:r)) [] fib !! 100000`` is as fast as using `zipWith'` ).

Comment: @WillNess, what would you call this function? ``grumble :: [a] -> [a]; grumble [] = []; grumble (x : xs) = x `seq` (x : grumble xs)``

Comment: Better: `grumble xs = [x | !x <- xs]`. With `INLINE` or maybe `INLINABLE`.

Comment: "forcing". yes, `foldr (\!x r->x:r) []` looks nicer.

Comment: @WillNess, I think they're pretty similar. The list comprehension plays better with GHC optimizations, because it uses `build`.